# Covering two data frames into one array of dimentionality (nrow, ncol, 2)

Tags: r, keras

I'm buliding keras model for mulitvariate time series classification. Data i'm using are separate in data frames by dimentions, so if there is an 2-variate time series I have 2 data frames each with the same number of columns (time stamps) and rows (observations). In this case my model should take the input (nrow, ncol, 2), but I have a problem with covering two data frames into one array of this dimentionality.
An example data can be found here: https://timeseriesclassification.com/description.php?Dataset=Libras

I know it's a basic question but I can't find any easy way to do this.

Example:

```
dim1 <- data.frame(t1 = c(1:4), t2 = c(2:5), t3 = c(3:6))
dim2 <- data.frame(t1 = c(3:6), t2 = c(4:7), t3 = c(5:8))
```

So expected result should return:

```
dim(result)
> 4 3 2
```

And be an array.

Comment: One of the expectations for this forum is that questions should include sample data (*in the form of code*) in them instead of a description of the data or a link to some data. Can you please include some fake sample data that we can load directly? That makes it easier for people to help and greatly increases the chance that you get advice that is relevant for your specific use case.

Comment: I add an example. Hope that I explain it properly, I think the key information is that it is use for keras classification model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `abind` function:

`?abind` Combine multi-dimensional arrays. This is a generalization of cbind and rbind. Takes a sequence of vectors, matrices, or arrays and produces a single array of the same or higher dimension.

```
library(abind)

# Combine data frames into a single array
result <- abind(dim1, dim2, along = 3)

dim(result)

[1] 4 3 2
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```r
d  <- array(
    unlist(c(dim1, dim2)),
    dim = c(4,3,2)
)

# Just to check
dim(d) # [1] 4 3 2
all(d[,,1] == dim1) # TRUE
all(d[,,2] == dim2) # TRUE
```